# Pandas - Creating a New Column

Tags: python, pandas

I have always made new columns in pandas using the following:

```
df['new_column'] = value
```

I am using this method, however, am receiving the warning for setting a copy.

What is the way to make a new column without creating a copy?

Comment: This way is one of several correct ways.  The warning you are getting is because `df` is a copy of something else and now you are trying to change `df`.  You should make sure that you are ok with `df` being decoupled from whatever it was you copied it from.  Once you are, you can either `df.is_copy = None` or `df = df.copy()`.  There are other ways to deal with it.  The way I like to ensure I don't ever see that is that when I create `df` from other soures, I usually do `df = other_df.loc[:, :]`  Using `loc` decouples it for me.  While `df = other_df[my_cols]` does not.

Comment: Provide the version for both python and pandas to clearly narrow down the root of the warning.

Comment: I interpreted the question to mean: how do I perform an in-place modification to an existing DataFrame where the modification is creating a new column by allocating more memory to the existing DataFrame, and not copying it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using

```
df.loc[:,'new column'] = value
```

As piRSquared comments, `df`is probably a copy of another DataFrame and when you set values to `df` it probably incurs in what is called *chain indexing*. Refer to [pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) for further information.