# Create a column from another

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataset in python / pandas where one column assumes the following values:
'1 - credit step' or '2 credit step'. Column id is C0340.
I am trying to create a new one, say C0900, that gets either the 1 and 2 (first position) as integer. The code I am using is as follows:

```
xl_file = pd.ExcelFile('C:/Users/e877780/Desktop/DEV/S2_SK_S_06_02_input.xlsx')
sheet1=xl_file.parse("S.06.02")
spread=sheet1[['C0040','C0090','C0170','C0290','C0340','C0360']]
spread['idx']=range(1,len(spread)+1)
spread.set_index('idx', inplace=True)
C0900=[]
for i in range(1, len(spread)+1):
    C0900.append(int(spread.loc[i]["C0340"][:1])
spread['C0900']=C0900
```

spread is the dataset where column C0340 is and C0900 is the new I mention above. Can anyone help?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by either the 1 and 2 (first position) as integer?  maybe some sample input and output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas - Creating a New Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41274332/pandas-creating-a-new-column)

Comment: The 1 and 2 are the first position of the possible values that column C0340 takes. For example, if say in line 3, the value for C0340 is '1 - credit step' then I want that the corresponding C0900 takes 1 (first position). Hope it is more clear.